# Divide the length of a given List

Tags: list, prolog

I want to divide the length of a given list. I know how to divide and I know how to obtain the length of a List, but using both predicates does not work for me. Here is what I got:

```
halflength(List,Halflength) :- length([List,Length]), Halflength is Length/2.

[trace]  ?- halflength([a,b,c],Halflength).
   Call: (7) halflength([a, b, c], _G15025) ? creep
   Call: (8) length([[a, b, c], _G15108]) ? creep
ERROR: halflength/2: Undefined procedure: length/1
ERROR:   However, there are definitions for:
ERROR:         length/2
   Exception: (8) length([[a, b, c], _G15108]) ? creep
   Exception: (7) halflength([a, b, c], _G15025) ? creep
```

Comment: And, `Halflength is Length/2` is problematic. Consider a one-element list. What should be half of it? `0.5`? or rather `0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
Undefined procedure: length/1
```

You are calling `length` with only one argument, a list:

```
length([List,Length])
```

This should be:

```
length(List, Length)
```

Comment: oh dear. Thank you very much!